# Flexbox margin between rows (margin-top: -xx)

Tags: css, flexbox

This is how it should work (spaces between hexagons horizontal and vertical):

[image: example1]

But when i add some elements (or resize browser window) flexbox automatically rescale all hexagons, but not margins.

I want to create full responsive (auto resize) hexagon area. I can do it using traditional media queries, but i need to create more flexible page.

[image: example2]

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/t9jnvr05/2/

```css
.row {
    display: flex !important;
}
.mx-1 {
    margin-right: .25rem !important;
    margin-left: .25rem !important;
}
.mr-1 {
    margin-right: .25rem !important;
}
.ml-1 {
    margin-left: .25rem !important;
}
.mt--5 {
    margin-top: -2.8rem !important;
}
.sh.v-hidden .sh-e .sh-c {
  visibility:hidden !important;
}
.sh.sh-hexagon.sh-4 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 207px;
}
.sh.sh-hexagon.sh-2 {
    width: 90px;
    height: 103.5px;
}
.sh.sh-hexagon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 46px;
}
.sh {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sh.sh-hexagon .sh-e {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.sh .sh-e, .sh .sh-e .sh-c {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.sh.sh-hexagon .sh-e .sh-c {
    transform: rotate(-120deg);
    background: red;
}
.sh .sh-e .sh-c {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<h3>1:</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-2 mr-1 v-hidden"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-2 ml-1 v-hidden"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
</div>

<h3>2:</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-2 mr-1 v-hidden"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-4 mx-1 mt--5"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
  <div class="sh sh-hexagon sh-2 ml-1 v-hidden"><div class="sh-e"><div class="sh-c"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That sort of layout is not something flexbox is designed to do. Flexbox works with **actual** rows...which do not really apply here,

Comment: You have the hexagons set to a flexible size (using percentage lengths), but you have their containers set to a fixed height (using `height: 207px`). So while the hexagons shrink, their containers keep full height. The difference between the two are those wide gaps. You'll need to make the containers a flexible size, as well.